# How to understand result parser of play2's anorm?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

This is a sample code from play2's built-in's zentasks:

```
object Project {

  // -- Parsers

  /**
   * Parse a Project from a ResultSet
   */
  val simple = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("project.id") ~
    get[String]("project.folder") ~
    get[String]("project.name") map {
      case id~folder~name => Project(id, folder, name)
    }
  }
}
```

Please notice the field keys: `project.id`, `project.folder`, `project.name`.

What does the `project` part mean? Where is it come from?

Look at the query method:

```
  def findById(id: Long): Option[Project] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("select * from project where id = {id}").on(
        'id -> id
      ).as(Project.simple.singleOpt)
    }
  }
```

The SQL is `select * from project ...`, the result should be:

```
    id    |    folder    |   name
```

Not:

```
    project.id    |    project.folder    |    project.name
```

Why we should specify the keys as `project.???`, but not `field name` directly?

How play2 use the `project.` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code available in [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/SqlParser.scala#L32), Anorm Parser uses the string provided to retrieve the given column.

As it gets some metadata, it requires teh full scope of the field (table + name) to work.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's just DB alias.

```
select id, folder, name from project
```

is the same as

```
select project.id, project.folder, project.name from project
```

or even

```
select p.id, p.folder, p.name from project p
```

Comment: Sorry, they are not DB aliases. It depends on the jdbc driver's `rs.getMetaData.getTableName(col)` method.